# code object is not signed at all - after rsync to linux, zip and unzip on mac

Tags: macos, rsync, macos-sierra, codesign

my workflow requires signing a mac .app, rsyncing to a linux box (rsync -aHv --acls --xattrs, also tried many other combinations), zipping together with other files and then deploying and unzipping to another mac.

on pre-macOS Sierra the .app opens and executes successfully, but on a Sierra osx box i'm getting "can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer" after verification. codesign -vv also spits "code object is not signed at all".

only if the .app is tar-ed and then transferred the .app runs without the "unidentified developer" error, but that is not an option.

any hints how to make this work? is it possible at all to preserve the .app so codesigning info is preserved?
diff/cmp didn't show any differences between a rsynced/zipped file and the original file

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's technical note [TN2206](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG18), the recommended way of distributing software is using signed dmg disk images. This is particularly true if you want your software to run on macOS Sierra. Please read this technical note where they explain possible errors (at the end of it) and how you can sign disk images. You can also use zip files, but Apple does not recommend this.